# Are $\therefore$ and $\because$ deprecated?

Tags: notation, math-history

I seldom see these symbols being used in modern mathematical texts.

I am wondering are these symbols deprecated? If not, under what conditions they will be used?

Edit: The question originally used the word "depleted". Sorry for using the wrong word. English is not my first language :)

Comment: They aren’t formal symbols, just word substitutions. Such symbols should only be used when space is limited. A particularly good usage is when writing on a blackboard, where the speaker speaks the word.

Comment: I think you mean "deprecated".  "Depleted" might have been relevant in the days of movable type, but hardly in the days of computer typesetting!

Comment: I mostly use them on proofs on exams. Saves space and time!

Comment: For just a single data point, I never even encountered $\because$ until one of my students used it and I had to ask her what it meant. I still use $\therefore$ a fair bit, but only as shorthand during a long list of implications.